# Gradient from Vectors type

Tags: simplifying-expressions, vector

I'm working with [`Vectors`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Vectors.html) type in `Mathematica` 9. For this purpose I use the following command:

```
Assumptions = v ϵ Vectors[3]
```

Now I want to find gradient from the next vector expression: $\vec{v}/\mid \vec{v}\mid$, but the
usual [`Grad`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Grad.html) function doesn't work with [`Vectors`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Vectors.html). I tried this:

```
Grad[v/Norm[v], v]
```

Question: Is it possible to find [`Grad`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Grad.html) or at least [`Norm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Norm.html) from variables of [`Vectors`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Vectors.html) type?

Comment: Not sure what you expect, but it seems like it works but with warnings.  Eg `TensorRank[Grad[v/Norm[v] , v]]` -> 2.  Maybe all you need is to surpress the warnings. Otherwise give more detail of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Note the difference between `$Assumptions` and `Assumptions`.

Comment: I hope to get something like $${\bigtriangledown}^{}_{v} \vec{v} / \mid \vec{v} \mid = \frac{1}{\mid \vec{v} \mid}[{\bigtriangledown}^{}_{v} \vec{v}-({\bigtriangledown}^{}_{v} \vec{v}* \frac{\vec{v}}{\mid \vec{v} \mid}) \otimes (\frac{\vec{v}}{\mid \vec{v} \mid})]$$
I know it is possible to do with Mathematica, but it seems like I chose the wrong functions for this purpose.

Comment: It seems unlikely in the best case mathematica would do that expansion for you.  Can you proove it to be true using lists (show code) then see what you get with abstract vectors?

Comment: Also, I'm `Assuming` the lack of a `$` on `$Assumptions` is a typo in your post, but you might want to edit that.